# How does recursion work for the following code, since a Boolean OR operation is used in the return statement?

Tags: c++, recursion

I came across this code, but I couldn't understand how the recursion works for the following code, as there's a Boolean OR operator used within a `return` statement, which I have never seen before. How is it supposed to work?

```
bool match(char *first, char * second)
{
    if (*first == '\0' && *second == '\0')
        return true;

    if (*first == '*' && *(first+1) != '\0' && *second == '\0')
        return false;

    if (*first == '?' || *first == *second)
        return match(first+1, second+1);

    if (*first == '*')
        return match(first+1, second) || match(first, second+1); //How does it work?
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works like all other disjunctions:

First the left-hand side, `match(first+1, second)` is evaluated.
If it is `true`, the result of the entire expression is `true` and nothing else is evaluated.
If it is `false`, the right-hand side, `match(first, second+1)` is evaluated and that becomes the result of the entire expression.

Comment: Note: An important consequence of this is that the second `match` call will never occur if the first returns `true`. Short-circuiting behavior is important if the calls might have side-effects. Obvious to people who know how `||` works, but given this question was asked, it's good to be clear.

Comment: @molbdnilo, does both the calls happen simultaneously?

Comment: @SubhadeepDey No, they happen in the order I stated. I tried to clarify the answer. (There is nothing special about the fact that these are recursive function calls. Everything proceeds as normal.)

Answer (score 1):

An important feature of the boolean operators `||` and `&&` is [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). That means in the case of `||` that if the first call `match(first + 1, second)` returns `true`, the second call will not be made, and `true` will be returned. Else the return value is the returned value of the second call.

Answer (score 0):

It works mostly as if a variable were assigned the parameter of `return`, then that variable returned. The only difference is, the compiler might do *return value optimization*.